# What is the role of & in this piece of code?

Tags: c++, openfoam

I am trying to understand dbns code in foam-extend. But I am having bit of doubt in a specific part of the following code given below.

deltaRLeft & gradrho[own]  or

deltaRRight & gradU[nei]

I thing & used here is a reference operator, but if any one can explain it in more detail, it will helpful for me.

```
    Flux::evaluateFlux
    (
        rhoFlux_[faceI],
        rhoUFlux_[faceI],
        rhoEFlux_[faceI],
        rho_[own] + rhoLimiter[own]*(deltaRLeft & gradrho[own]),
        rho_[nei] + rhoLimiter[nei]*(deltaRRight & gradrho[nei]),
        U_[own] + cmptMultiply(ULimiter[own], (deltaRLeft & gradU[own])),
        U_[nei] + cmptMultiply(ULimiter[nei], (deltaRRight & gradU[nei])),
        T_[own] + TLimiter[own]*(deltaRLeft & gradT[own]),
        T_[nei] + TLimiter[nei]*(deltaRRight & gradT[nei]),
        R[own],
        R[nei],
        Cv[own],
        Cv[nei],
        Cp[own],
        Cp[nei],
        Sf[faceI],
        magSf[faceI]
    );
```

What is the & exactly doing here, if it can be explained in detail.
The part of the code is from dbns/numericFlux/numericFlux.C

Answer (score 2):

It's the bitwise and operator.

It compares each bit of the first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand. 
If both bits are 1, the result bit is set to 1 otherwise 0.

As example:

```
     11001001  
   & 10111000 
     -------- 
   = 10001000
```

Comment: The operator & is overloaded by the OpenFOAM classes. See the answer of @Herpes-Free-Engineer

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405473/3393574) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405490/3393574) answers are mostly not applicable within the OpenFOAM context.

In the OpenFOAM context, `&` is the [inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html) if the operands are tensors. Thereat, `deltaRRight` and `gradT[nei]` are in fact tensor objects.

Please look at the [OpenFOAM's programmers' guide](http://foam.sourceforge.net/docs/Guides-a4/ProgrammersGuide.pdf), Section 1.4.1 and 1.3.1.

Comment: This is the correct answer in the context of OpenFOAM. Why is nobody upvoting it? Or accept it as correct (@Bidesh-Sengupta)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different `&` operators.

The bitwise AND operator (&) compares each bit of the first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0.

Both operands to the bitwise AND operator must be of integral types.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   unsigned short a = 0xFFFF;      // pattern 1111 ...
   unsigned short b = 0xAAAA;      // pattern 1010 ...

   cout  << hex << ( a & b ) << endl;   // prints "aaaa", pattern 1010 ...
}
```